# Mysql subquery always doing filesort

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have a table gamesplatform_pricehistory with an index :
(`id_app`,`country`,`dateup`)

doing this

```
explain select dateup from gamesplatform_pricehistory
    where id_app=1 and country=1
    order by dateup desc limit 1
```

shows "Using where; Using index"

but with a subquery :

```
explain select app.id, (select dateup from gamesplatform_pricehistory
                           where id_app=app.id and country=1
                           order by dateup desc limit 1)
      from app where id > 0;
```

shows Using where; Using index; Using filesort

Here is a sqlfiddle showing directly the problem :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/034bc/1

benchmark with millions rows :
(table games_platform is the same as app) :

```
SELECT sql_no_cache thepricehistory.dateup
    FROM games_platform
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(dateup) as dateup, id_app
                   FROM gamesplatform_pricehistory
                   WHERE country='229' GROUP BY id_app
              ) thepricehistory
                         ON thepricehistory.id_app =games_platform.id
    WHERE games_platform.id=2
```

eval : 0.8s

```
SELECT sql_no_cache ( SELECT dateup FROM gamesplatform_pricehistory
                        WHERE id_app= games_platform.id AND country='229'
                        ORDER BY dateup DESC LIMIT 1
                    ) AS dateup
    FROM games_platform
    WHERE games_platform.id=2
```

eval : 0.0003s

Comment: have you tried this with a table with more than 2 rows? the query optimiser will probably just do a whole table scan if it's only a small table.

Comment: yes, a more complex query but with a table with millions of rows and the same subquery will still do the same

Comment: Probably something to do with MySQL being able to use only one index at a time. I haven't got time to unpick it, but have you tried rewriting this to use a join and a group by?

Comment: see below, with a group by looks worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Using filesort` isn't necessarily a bad thing. The name is a bit misleading. Though it contains "file", it does not mean, that the data is written anywhere on hard disk. It still is just processed in memory.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html):

> MySQL must do an extra pass to find out how to retrieve the rows in sorted order. The sort is done by going through all rows according to the join type and storing the sort key and pointer to the row for all rows that match the WHERE clause. The keys then are sorted and the rows are retrieved in sorted order. See Section [8.2.1.11, “ORDER BY Optimization”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

You understand why this happens in your query, right? Using this kind of subqueries is bad style since it's a **dependent** subquery. For every row in your `app` table the subquery is executed. Very bad. Rewrite the query with a `join`.

```
select app.id,
gp.dateup
from app 
join gamesplatform_pricehistory gp on gp.id_app = app.id
where app.id > 0
and gp.country = 1
and gp.dateup = (SELECT MAX(dateup) FROM gamesplatform_pricehistory smgp WHERE smgp.id_app = gp.id_app AND smgp.country = 1)
;
```

This still uses a dependent subquery, but the `explain` looks much better:

```
| id |        select_type | table |  type | possible_keys |     key | key_len |                        ref | rows |                    Extra |
|----|--------------------|-------|-------|---------------|---------|---------|----------------------------|------|--------------------------|
|  1 |            PRIMARY |   app | index |       PRIMARY | PRIMARY |       4 |                     (null) |    2 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 |            PRIMARY |    gp |   ref |        id_app |  id_app |       5 |    db_2_034bc.app.id,const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |  smgp |   ref |        id_app |  id_app |       5 | db_2_034bc.gp.id_app,const |    1 |              Using index |
```

Another way to rewrite it, would be this:

```
select app.id,
gp.dateup
from app 
LEFT join 
(SELECT id_app, MAX(dateup) AS dateup 
 FROM gamesplatform_pricehistory
 WHERE country = 1
 GROUP BY id_app
)gp on gp.id_app = app.id
where app.id > 0
;
```

The explain looks even better:

```
| id | select_type |                      table |  type | possible_keys |     key | key_len |    ref | rows |                    Extra |
|----|-------------|----------------------------|-------|---------------|---------|---------|--------|------|--------------------------|
|  1 |     PRIMARY |                        app | index |       PRIMARY | PRIMARY |       4 | (null) |    2 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 |     PRIMARY |                 <derived2> |   ALL |        (null) |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |    2 |                          |
|  2 |     DERIVED | gamesplatform_pricehistory | index |        (null) |  id_app |      13 | (null) |    2 | Using where; Using index |
```

And here is a version where you have no dependent subquery at all:

```
select app.id,
gp.dateup
from app 
left join gamesplatform_pricehistory gp on gp.id_app = app.id and country = 1
left join gamesplatform_pricehistory gp2 on gp.id_app = app.id and country = 1 and gp.dateup < gp2.dateup
where app.id > 0
and gp2.dateup is null
;
```

It works like this: When `gp.dateup` is at its maximum, there is no `gp2.dateup`.

Comment: thank you.The subquery isn't executed on every row matching the "where" ? why the subquery uses filesort and not when doing the query directly ?

Comment: this is what I got using your last request, with the group :1  PRIMARY  <derived4>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 118313  
4  DERIVED  gamesplatform_pricehistory  range  NULL id_app  5  NULL 373772  Using where; Using index for group-by <----- it doesn't looks better, it has a lot more rows than before (I had 1, now it shows 373772 and 118313)

Comment: Yes, matching the `where`, of course, I meant to say for every row of the outer query.

Comment: Notice, that I did a `left join`, I was assuming you wanted to return results, even if there's no matching entry in your `gamesplatform_pricehistory` table. So it's doing a whole table scan since you don't have a suitable index on your `app` table. The second part of your explain doesn't look bad. Include such information in your question. It's hard to read in the comments

Comment: yes, left join. Yes I want results even where there is no matching in pricehistory. I have a suitable index on app, I have a primary key on id, which is the only column used on this request

Comment: What you `select` is of less interest when indexing, except when everything you query is also in the index (in the proper order). Which is the case here, but still you're reading the whole table, so looking up the index first, would mean an extra step. That's why MySQL skips using the index here.

Comment: it looks worse to have a lot of rows with "where, index for group by" than 1 row with "where, index and filsort", no ?

Comment: How about you just have a try? I'm not too sure right now, but it might also be, that you just have one row, because you do `limit 1` and the index is used for `order by`. Still your query gets executed multiple times with my last approach it gets executed once. Have a try how long it takes, I still bet mine is faster.

Comment: Well, like I already said in my answer, it depends on the data. When your data size grows it might be that my query is faster. Who knows...

Comment: the two tables involved contains multiple millions rows

Comment: @user3416510 I added another way of rewriting the query to my answer, without a dependent subquery this time. Please have a try with it. Your sqlfiddle doesn't work anymore, I get a 404, so I can't say anything about the `explain` output.

Comment: the sqlfiddle is still working for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/034bc/1 . Your query won't work. I only need the latest "dateup" entry, not all of them. In my "real" request, I also need the "price" in the one before the last. (
  SELECT price FROM gamesplatform_pricehistory WHERE id_app= games_platform.id AND country='229' ORDER BY dateup DESC LIMIT 1,1
 ) AS oldprice

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

One of these composite indexes is likely to be helpful:

```
INDEX(id_app, country, dateup)
INDEX(country, id_app, dateup)
```

Comment: on sqlfiddle you can see the indexes :ALTER TABLE `gamesplatform_pricehistory`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `id_app` (`id_app`,`country`,`dateup`);