# What is the correct index for this query?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 5.6 I have to create an index specifically for this subselect:

```
UPDATE site
SET site.shipping_address_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM platform_address
    WHERE owner_id = site.numeric_id AND owner_type = 'site' AND deleted = 0
    ORDER BY modified_time
    LIMIT 1
),
    site.postal_address_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM platform_address
    WHERE owner_id = site.numeric_id AND owner_type = 'site' AND deleted = 0
    ORDER BY modified_time
    LIMIT 1
);
```

My initial thought was:

```
create index tmp_platform_address_for_site on platform_address (owner_id, owner_type, deleted, modified_time, id);
```

Since it's an exact filter on the first 3 columns. It was my understanding that the query planner would be smart enough to use the `modified_time` after that, then since the `id` is in the index it wouldn't have to hit the table at all.

However, the plan looks like:

```
1   PRIMARY site    index   PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE,numeric_id_UNIQUE,fk_site_company1,i_default_price_list_id,site_ModifiedTime  PRIMARY 108     11  Using temporary
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  platform_address    ref tmp_platform_address_for_site   tmp_platform_address_for_site   8   site.numeric_id,const,const 1   Using where; Using index; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  platform_address    ref tmp_platform_address_for_site   tmp_platform_address_for_site   8   site.numeric_id,const,const 1   Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: (site.numeric_id) Is this a correlated subquery? I suggest you may need to show us the complete query.

Comment: I've added the full query and explain.

Comment: refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038726/mysql-subquery-always-doing-filesort